# How to create new dataframe from rows with dictionaries?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In Python3 and pandas I have a one column dataframe. On each line there is a list, with dictionaries inside. It was obtained from a file:

```
import pandas as pd

geral = pd.read_csv("mandados_12_abr_2018_RJ.csv",sep=';',encoding = 'latin_1')

geral.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5298 entries, 0 to 5297
Data columns (total 4 columns):
mandados     5298 non-null object
mensagem     0 non-null float64
paginador    5298 non-null object
sucesso      5298 non-null bool
dtypes: bool(1), float64(1), object(2)
memory usage: 129.4+ KB

df1 = pd.DataFrame(geral['mandados'])

df1.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5298 entries, 0 to 5297
Data columns (total 1 columns):
mandados    5298 non-null object
dtypes: object(1)
memory usage: 41.5+ KB
```

Sample content, of column "mandados" -  a list, with dictionaries inside:

```
[{'id': 409, 'numeroMandado': '2251-65.2012.8.19.0066.0001', 'nomeParte': 'CARLOS HENRIQUE BELARMINO DE OLIVEIRA', 'dataMandado': '2012-01-31', 'orgao': 'TJRJ', 'situacao': 'Aguardando Cumprimento', 'detalhes': ['Data de nascimento: 02/07/1987', 'Nacionalidade: Brasileira', 'Sexo: Masculino', 'Nome da Genitora: Luiza Maria Belarmino Dias', 'Nome do Genitor: Geraldo De Oliveira', 'Carteira de identidade: 213004088']}, {'id': 408, 'numeroMandado': '11451-97.2012.8.19.0001.0001', 'nomeParte': 'DANIEL NASCIMENTO SILVA', 'dataMandado': '2012-01-31', 'orgao': 'TJRJ', 'situacao': 'Aguardando Cumprimento', 'detalhes': ['Sexo: Masculino', 'Nacionalidade: Brasileira', 'Nome do Genitor: Não Declarado', 'Data de nascimento: 27/02/1993', 'Nome da Genitora: Marluce Nascimento Silva', 'Carteira de identidade: 276885555']}, {'id': 407, 'numeroMandado': '11451-97.2012.8.19.0001.0002', 'nomeParte': 'THIAGO SABINO DA SILVA', 'dataMandado': '2012-01-31', 'orgao': 'TJRJ', 'situacao': 'Aguardando Cumprimento', 'detalhes': ['Nome do Genitor: Joao Batista Benvindo Da Silva', 'Sexo: Masculino', 'Nome da Genitora: Eliza Sabino Miranda', 'Data de nascimento: 02/03/1988', 'Nacionalidade: Brasileira', 'Carteira de identidade: 216708446']}, ...
```

I want to create a new dataframe in which columns are the items of the dictionaries in each row of the "df1" dataframe. Selecting only these columns:

```
nomeParte, orgao, numeroMandado, dataMandado, situacao and detalhes
```

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: It is possible. Probably would be better to figure out a way to create it directly from the `.csv`.

Comment: Thank you. Do you mean read the CSV and just select the column "mandados" and the desired columns within it?

Comment: A bit confused with the provided sample but to clarify `mandados` is a list of dictionaries? Because although you mention that, the first list `]` is closed off right before `paginador`

Comment: Your data is sloppy and malformed.  Can you edit your post so that its readable and copy/paste-able?

Comment: Thanks, I've put up examples of more lines. I can send the file if it is better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could post just the first few rows of your .csv, so that I could ensure I have the same data, that would be helpful. But this seems to do what you want:

```
list_dicts = [{'id': 409, 'numeroMandado': '2251-65.2012.8.19.0066.0001', 'nomeParte': 'CARLOS HENRIQUE BELARMINO DE OLIVEIRA', 'dataMandado': '2012-01-31', 'orgao': 'TJRJ', 'situacao': 'Aguardando Cumprimento', 'detalhes': ['Data de nascimento: 02/07/1987', 'Nacionalidade: Brasileira', 'Sexo: Masculino', 'Nome da Genitora: Luiza Maria Belarmino Dias', 'Nome do Genitor: Geraldo De Oliveira', 'Carteira de identidade: 213004088']}, {'id': 408, 'numeroMandado': '11451-97.2012.8.19.0001.0001', 'nomeParte': 'DANIEL NASCIMENTO SILVA', 'dataMandado': '2012-01-31', 'orgao': 'TJRJ', 'situacao': 'Aguardando Cumprimento', 'detalhes': ['Sexo: Masculino', 'Nacionalidade: Brasileira', 'Nome do Genitor: Não Declarado', 'Data de nascimento: 27/02/1993', 'Nome da Genitora: Marluce Nascimento Silva', 'Carteira de identidade: 276885555']}, {'id': 407, 'numeroMandado': '11451-97.2012.8.19.0001.0002', 'nomeParte': 'THIAGO SABINO DA SILVA', 'dataMandado': '2012-01-31', 'orgao': 'TJRJ', 'situacao': 'Aguardando Cumprimento', 'detalhes': ['Nome do Genitor: Joao Batista Benvindo Da Silva', 'Sexo: Masculino', 'Nome da Genitora: Eliza Sabino Miranda', 'Data de nascimento: 02/03/1988', 'Nacionalidade: Brasileira', 'Carteira de identidade: 216708446']}]
cols = ["nomeParte", "orgao", "numeroMandado", "dataMandado", "situacao", "detalhes"]
df = pd.DataFrame(list_dicts)[cols]
```

where I've just copy-pasted in the list of dictionaries from your post. You have this list as a column of another dataframe, correct? And that's what's giving you issues? If this list is the column `'mandados'` of `geral`, I think you could do

```
pd.DataFrame(mandados.geral.tolist())[cols]
```

EDIT - after looking at the data in question

The format of this data file is quite unusual, but we can get what you want. Two main things:

1. when you read in the file as a csv, the values in the `mandados` column are just read as strings (they're not converted into lists or such automatically); this is normal and expected behavior. We'll have to do the conversion ourselves.
2. It seems that each row in `mandados` is a list of dictionaries - I'm assuming that you want a dataframe made from the combination of all of those lists?

Here's something that I think will do what you want: first we convert from strings to lists of dictionaries (using `literal_eval`; this is a safe version of `eval`; it will just convert strings that could be viewed as Python lists, tuples, dicts, and numeric types into those types, but it won't execute arbitrary code) then we combine all of the lists into one, and finally make a dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
from ast import literal_eval

df = pd.read_csv('mandados_12_abr_2018_RJ.csv', sep=';')
all_lists = sum((literal_eval(l) for l in df.mandados.tolist()), [])
cols = ["nomeParte", "orgao", "numeroMandado", "dataMandado", "situacao", "detalhes"]
df = pd.DataFrame(all_lists)[cols]
```

Comment: Thank you. I performed - mandados = pd.DataFrame(geral.mandados.tolist())[cols]  - and this error appeared: KeyError: "['nomeParte' 'orgao' 'numeroMandado' 'dataMandado' 'situacao' 'detalhes'] not in index"

Comment: Is that the index in geral are: mandados, mensagem, paginador and sucesso. And within "mandados" are the lists with dictionaries

Comment: The file here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nNKjF72UATblSmauUCII-V4loV-_RvfG/view?usp=sharing